# DataGridView - Make whole cell clickable not only text

Tags: c#, datagridview

As the title says I can't figure out how to make the whole cell of a DataGridView clickable in c#, currently it only works when clicking exactly at the point where the text is.

Comment: instead of taking DataGridView textbox column, try to use button column to fix your problem.

Comment: I checked in a sample program and the cell enters into edit mode whenever I click anywhere on the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CellClick` event of DataGridView.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
 private void DataGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
}
```